# Build a Sticky Scrollview in famo.us

Tags: famo.us

I am trying to build a Sticky scrollview in famo.us and I am getting stuck in two places.

1) The body scrolls on top of the header. When I add a Transform.translate(0, 0, 1) to the header before adding it to the _mainScrollview it does nothing.

2) How do I keep the velocity going on the _bodyScrollview when the _mainScrollview gets stuck?

```
/***
 * A view that scrolls, sticks the header at stickAt,
 * and then allows the body to scroll.
 */
function Sticky(options) {
    View.apply(this, arguments);

    options = options || {};

    this.options = Object.create(Sticky.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    for (var i in Sticky.DEFAULT_OPTIONS) {
        if (options[i] !== undefined) this.options[i] = options[i];
    }

    // setup the scrollviews

    this._bodyScrollview = new Scrollview({});
    this._bodyScrollview.sequenceFrom([this.options.body]);

    this._mainScrollview = new Scrollview({});
    this._mainScrollview.sequenceFrom([this.options.header, this._bodyScrollview]);
    this._eventInput.pipe(this._mainScrollview);

    // track the velocities

    this._mainScrollview.sync.on('update', function (data) {
        this._mainVelocity = data.velocity;
    }.bind(this));

    this._bodyScrollview.sync.on('update', function (data) {
        this._bodyVelocity = data.velocity;
    }.bind(this));

    this.add(this._mainScrollview);
}

Sticky.prototype.render = function () {
    // If the main scrollview is scrolled up (velocity < 0)
    // past the stickAt point, stick it and unstick the body scrollview.
    if (this._mainVelocity < 0) {
        if (this._mainScrollview.getPosition() >= this.options.stickAt) {
            this._eventInput.unpipe(this._mainScrollview);
            this._eventInput.pipe(this._bodyScrollview);

            Tools.forcePosition(this._mainScrollview, this.options.stickAt, true);

            this._mainVelocity = 0;
        }
    }

    // If the main scrollview is scrolled down (velocity > 0)
    // past 0, stick it and unstick the main scrollview.
    if (this._bodyVelocity > 0) {
        console.log(this._bodyScrollview.getPosition());
        if (this._bodyScrollview.getPosition() <= 0) {
            this._eventInput.unpipe(this._bodyScrollview);
            this._eventInput.pipe(this._mainScrollview);

            Tools.forcePosition(this._bodyScrollview, 0, true);

            this._bodyVelocity = 0;
        }
    }

    return View.prototype.render.call(this);
};

/**
 * Force a scrollview to a position
 */
Tools.forcePosition = function (scrollview, position, noSpring) {
    if (noSpring) {
        scrollview._springState = 0;
        scrollview._physicsEngine.detachAll();
    }

    scrollview.setVelocity(0);
    scrollview.setPosition(position);    
};
```

Comment: The source is at http://github.com/famous/famous and docs are at https://famo.us/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a famous-flex FlexScrollView, see this demo:

https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex-chat

Tutorial: https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex/blob/master/tutorials/FlexScrollView.md

Answer (score 0):

1) I suspect your Header size is wrong and overlaps the main scroll content. Check using the inspecter and modify size as necessary. (See the Famo.us [Common pitfalls: Why am I not getting this click?](https://famo.us/guides/dev/pitfalls.html))

2) Subscribe to the `edgeHit` event of the Scroller and manually set velocity (like you do when you're stopping the scroller).

BTW, instead of having this

```
ScrollView
    HeaderSurface
    ScrollView
        Content
```

I would layout like this:

```
 HeaderSurface
 ScrollView
     HeaderSurface
     Content1
     Content2
     Content3
```

<del>So a single HeaderSurface is referenced twice in the RenderTree.</del>So I would clone the HeaderSurface and if you scroll past a certain point, you show the first (sticky) HeaderSurface. This overlaps the second (scrollviewed) HeaderSurface.

Comment: 1) works in safari. I am guessing it has to do with the intersecting surfaces bug in Chrome mentioned here https://famo.us/guides/dev/pitfalls.html

Comment: Also for future viewers, adding a RenderNode in two trees does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

1) This turned out to be a problem with Chrome, it works on safari. The workaround was to create the header after the body.

2) Passing around velocities proved to be difficult and complex -- when I would stick the header the body would bounce because it was inside the same scrollview.

I rebuilt the view to use one scrollview with a filler node representing the header. Then I manually transform the header depending on where the scrollview is.

```
HeaderSurface
BodyScrollview
    HeaderFiller
    BodySurface
```

Here is the code:

```
/***
 * A view that scrolls sticks the header at stickHeaderAt
 * and allows the body to scroll underneath the header.
 */
function Sticky(options) {
    View.apply(this, arguments);

    options = options || {};

    this.options = Object.create(Sticky.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    for (var i in Sticky.DEFAULT_OPTIONS) {
        if (options[i] !== undefined) this.options[i] = options[i];
    }

    // Setup the body scrollview.

    // Add a filler node to represent the header.
    // In render we will manually transform the header depending on where the scrollview is.
    var headerFiller = new RenderNode(new Modifier({
        size: this.options.header.getSize()
    }));
    headerFiller.add(new Surface);

    this._bodyScrollview = new Scrollview({});
    this._bodyScrollview.sequenceFrom([headerFiller, this.options.body]);

    this.add(this._bodyScrollview);

    this._eventInput.pipe(this._bodyScrollview);

    // Create a wrapping container surface for the header after
    // the body as a workaround of a bug where chrome does not
    // respect our transform on the header.

    var headerContainer = new ContainerSurface({
        size: this.options.header.getSize(),
        transform: Transform.translate(0, 0, 1)
    });
    headerContainer.add(this.options.header);

    // Setup the header node.

    // Transform the header on top of the body (broken in chrome).
    this._headerModifier = new StateModifier({
        transform: Transform.translate(0, 0, 1)
    });
    var headerNode = new RenderNode(this._headerModifier);
    headerNode.add(headerContainer);

    this.add(headerNode);
}

Sticky.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
Sticky.constructor = Sticky;

Sticky.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
    header: null,
    body: null,
    stickHeaderAt: 0
};

Sticky.prototype.render = function () {
    // If the body scrollview is on the first page handle sticking / unsticking the header.
    // Otherwise the body is scrolled up enought that the header is already stuck, so ignore it.
    if (this._bodyScrollview._node.getNext()) {
        var scrollviewPosition = this._bodyScrollview.getPosition();

        // Stop the header when the scrollview hits stickHeaderAt.
        if (scrollviewPosition > this.options.stickHeaderAt) {
            this._headerModifier.setTransform(Transform.translate(0, -1 * this.options.stickHeaderAt, 1));
        }
        // When the scrollview is below the stickHeaderAt point
        // move the header with the scrollview.
        else {
            this._headerModifier.setTransform(Transform.translate(0, -1 * scrollviewPosition, 1));
        }
    }

    return View.prototype.render.call(this);
};

/**
 * Reset the header and body to the top.
 */
Sticky.prototype.reset = function () {
    this._headerModifier.setTransform(Transform.translate(0, 0, 1));

    this._bodyScrollview.goToPreviousPage();
    Tools.forcePosition(this._bodyScrollview, 0, true);
};
```